# Sending Audio streams to different ports

Tags: iphone, playback

I've a requirement to play different streams to different ports.
Something like: 
We want to send one audio stream (for example music to the ipod connector or external speaker) and one audio stream (for example movie) to the headphone connector.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on iOS. We cannot play different audio from different ports.